# A question about Noetherian one-dimensional domains.

Tags: commutative-algebra

If $R$ is a one-dimensional Noetherian domains, not Dedekind. It is true that each localization with a maximal ideal is a DVR, since the localization is a one dimensional Noetherian local domain. My question is: is this reasoning correct, even if $R$ is not integrally closed?

Comment: Of course is not! If all localizations are DVRs, then the ring is Dedekind.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I have another doubt. If I have a one-dimensional Noetherian domain, not ntegrally closed, from the algebraic point of view, why are some localizations not DVRs? I thnk that can increase the dimenson of the localization, but I can't view an exemple.